# map one dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the food quantity for an individual:

```
set.seed(1)
quantity <- data.frame(apple = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                       egg = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                       beer = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

eg. the first person ate 8 apple, 6 eggs and drank 0 beers, 5 person in total

I also have a reference table with market weights and nutrient intake:

```
reference <- data.frame(name = c("apple", "apple", "egg", "beer", "beer", "beer"),
                        market_weight = c(0.4, 0.6, 1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1),
                        nutr1 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE),
                        nutr2 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE),
                        nutr3 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE))
```

for each person, I need to know the nutrient intake (ie. nutr1) according to the food quantities they eat.

Expected result (5 rows - each for participants):

```
nutr1    nutr2    nutr3
7814.8  4996.4    9053.6  
  W        T        K  
.....    ....     .....
```

My (inefficient) solution:

here I join quantities and nutrient intake

```
library(dplyr)
merged <- quantity %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("name","id1","id2", "id3", "id4", "id5")) %>%
  right_join(., reference, by= "name") %>%
  na.omit
```

here I multiply `quantities * market_weight * nutrients` (1 to 3) and sum for each nutrient

```
out <- merged %>%
  mutate(mutr1_final = id1 * market_weight * nutr1,
         mutr2_final = id1 * market_weight * nutr2,
         mutr3_final = id1 * market_weight * nutr3) %>%
  summarise_at(., vars(c(mutr1_final, mutr2_final, mutr3_final)), funs(sum))
```

With real data, the dataframe quantity contains 40k lines (aka participants) and the number of nutrients is 80-ish.
What it is an efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: how is the type of apple or beer taken into consideration?

Comment: @DanielO just a way to clarify `weight`. Red apple weighs .4 while green apple weighs .6. In practice, is not useful for the code

Comment: Person 1 has 8 apples, how can I possible know how many nutrients they ingested if I don't know which type from the reference table to use in the calculation?

Comment: I just edited the question and removed the unnecessary `type` variable - hope it's clearer. The weight represent the `market_weight` so 8 apples are divided like this: 8*0.4 with some nutrient values, 8*0.6 with other nutrient values

Comment: Can you give the desired output in actual numbers for at least 1 person? What your asking doesn't make sense, are you adding 8*0.4*... + 8*0.6*...? are you assuming that they ate all types of apples?

Comment: I already did it - look at my solution and there you'll find everything

Comment: It is common for the person asking to include the actual output with numbers. That way you are giving less work for those trying to help. They can see the final product without having to execute your code...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I edited it! As for the second part of your comment, I'm actually not asking _whether_ it make sense or not, only if there's a more efficient way to do this calculation

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
set.seed(1)
quantity <- data.frame(apple = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                       egg = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                       beer = sample(0:10, 5, replace = TRUE))

reference <- data.frame(name = c("apple", "apple", "egg", "beer", "beer", "beer"),
                        market_weight = c(0.4, 0.6, 1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1),
                        nutr1 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE),
                        nutr2 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE),
                        nutr3 = sample(1:999, 6, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
 # multiply market_weight by nutrients 
  mutate(nutr1 = market_weight*nutr1,          
         nutr2 = market_weight*nutr2,
         nutr3 = market_weight*nutr3) %>%
 # sum within fruit name
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-market_weight)

# merge quantity and reference (same line: quantity and combined food intake)
merged <- t(quantity) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(., "name") %>%
  right_join(., reference, by="name")

# multiplication and summation
out <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=3) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  `colnames<-`(colnames(reference)[2:4])
for(i in 2:6) {
  for(j in 7:9){
    out[i-1,j-6] = sum(merged[, i] * merged[, j])
  }
}
```

more efficient solutions are appreciated!